# Tagging photos when importing them from my Galaxy Note

Tags: photos, samsung-galaxy-note

I tried to import the photos I have in my Galaxy Note. While importing them the computer asked if I would add a tag to them -- and I did.

The strange thing is that when the computer finished importing the pictures, I found pictures of strange people in the same folder and with the same tag!

Does this mean that my photos will appear to whoever chooses the same tag?

Comment: Do you have those strange pics on you phone as well? If you happened to import them via USB they must have come from your SD card. To answer your question: No, other people of course cannot access your pics if they use the same tag.